# Attempt to create a future Date instead created a past Date

Tags: javascript, date, locale

My current datetime is **April 8th, 8:52 PM**, and I'm using this code:

```
//get current time
var now = new Date();

//get current time plus 6 hours in the future
var future = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), now.getHours()+6, now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(), 0);

//print result
console.log(future.toLocaleString());
```

The result is `4/6/2016, 2:52:43 AM`. The time is actually correct, but the day is somehow going backwards 2 days. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.getDay()` returns the day of the week (0-6).

What you want is `.getDate()` instead, which returns the day of the month.

---

If you are going to do a lot of date manipulation, you should check out [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

In moment you can just do:

```
var future = moment.add(6, 'hours');
```

Comment: This was driving me crazy, it makes sense now. The correct method should be `.getDate()` which is kind of confusing semantically-wise. Thanks for the heads-up!